# Request PDF via POST using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, http-headers

I have a Webservice which creates a PDF out of a JSON Object.
In my Web Application I want to display that PDF in the Browser.

So I want the Browser to send a POST-Request which uses Request Content-Type: application/json and my JSON Object.

This is not a problem by using an AJAX-Call. But then I have the PDF as string and no idea how to render that string as PDF.

The other possibility would be to advise the browser to load the PDF as next page to show. But it seems there is no way to modify the Request Content-Type used to load a Page. When I use a Form-Tag the Request Content-Type is always application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I found others having the same problem on the Internet. But haven't found a solution to it.
But since it seems such a standard problem to me I can not believe there is no solution to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Webservice which creates a PDF out of a JSON Object" then later "I have the PDF as string" - so now does the webservice **actually** create a PDF? Or what?

Comment: The Webservice creates a PDF. But when I get it via XMLReqeust there is no PDF specific representation available. So I get the content of the Sever response, which is a PDF, as string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to pass the PDF data using data protocol (e.g. data:application/pdf,base64;ABC....=) to the window.open; depends on the web browser it may or may not handle that long URL

Another way is to feed it to some HTML/JS library, e.g. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js. There are Flash alternatives as well.

Comment: It seems to work in Firefox, Chrom, Konqueror.

I have not yet checked in Safari.

Internet Explorer seems to have Problems with it. I don't know why.
According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Internet Explorer supports data: but has up to IE8 a limitation of 32KB.
I could live with that.

I will tell when I figured the IE Problem out.

Comment: Safari can handle it. But I had to save it to disk and change the name to .pdf to see it. Just open the link does not work.

Comment: I did not really find out why Internet Explorer does not like it. Wikipedia sais it is because of security reasons, others say Data URI Sheme is just not supported for externel links.